# ASP.NET MVC Route Default values

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-routing

i defined two routes in global.asax like below

```
context.MapRoute("HomeRedirect", "",
                            new
                            {
                                controller = "Home",
                                action = "redirect"
                            });

context.MapRoute("UrlResolver", "{culture}/some",
                            new
                            {
                                culture = "en-gb",
                                controller = "someController",
                                action = "someAction"
                            },
                            new
                            {
                                culture = new CultureRouteConstraint()
                            });
```

according to above definition, when user request mysite.com/ redirect action of HomeController should be called and in that:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Redirect()
    {
        return RedirectToRoute("UrlResolver");
    }
}
```

i want to redirect user to second defined route on above, so also i specified default values for that and some Constraint for each of those. but when `RedirectToRoute("UrlResolver")` turns, no default values passed to routeConstraints on second route and `No route in the route table matches the supplied values` shows.

**update**

my CultureRouteConstraint:

```
public class CultureRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    bool IRouteConstraint.Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        try
        {
            var parameter = values[parameterName] as string;
            return (someCondition(parameter));
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

now values parameter haven't culture key/value, but route parameter have that.

Comment: have you recompiled your application? I created a sample app using my understanding of your problem and wasn't able to replicate your error. I instead got what I understand to be your expected results (redirection to the UrlResolver route)

Comment: yes, i recompiled; my problem is that when i use RedirectToRoute, default value of culture for second route is null (there is no route key/value on RouteValueDictionary to retrive value on CultureRouteConstraint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual *route* specified for your second rule is "{culture}/some", so your redirect would have to be, for example, to "/EN-us/some" rather than to the name of the rule.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of HomeController.Redirect() doesn't seem to add any additional value, so why include the route named "HomeRedirect" at all?

How about just deleting it and letting your route named "UrlResolver" handle the requests. You can configure the defaults as you like.

You might add a "catch all" route below the "UrlResolver" route to catch cases where the CultureRouteConstraint() doesn't match the given URL.